# tomcat gives 404 error while my mapping in xml is fine

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

```
public class Guestbook extends CacheHttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;
    private Vector < GuestbookEntry > entries = new Vector < GuestbookEntry > ();
    private long lastModified = 0; // Time last entry was added
    // Display the current entries, then ask for a new entry
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        printHeader(out);
        printForm(out);
        printMessages(out);
        printFooter(out);
    }
    // Add a new entry, then dispatch back to doGet()
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        handleForm(req, res);
        doGet(req, res);
    }
    private void printHeader(PrintWriter out) throws ServletException {
        out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Guestbook</TITLE></HEAD>");
        out.println("<BODY>");
    }
    private void printForm(PrintWriter out) throws ServletException {
        out.println("<FORM METHOD=POST action='/hello.html'>"); // posts to itself
        out.println("<B>Please submit your feedback:</B><BR>");
        out.println("Your name: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=name><BR>");
        out.println("Your email: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=email><BR>");
        out.println("Comment: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=50 NAME=comment><BR>");
        out.println("<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE=\"Send Feedback\"><BR>");
        out.println("</FORM>");
        out.println("<HR>");
    }
    private void printMessages(PrintWriter out) throws ServletException {
        String name, email, comment;
        Enumeration < GuestbookEntry > e = entries.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            GuestbookEntry entry = (GuestbookEntry) e.nextElement();
            name = entry.name;
            if (name == null) {
                name = "Unknown user";
                email = "Unknown email";
            }
            email = entry.email;
            comment = entry.comment;
            if (comment == null) comment = "No comment";
            out.println("<DL>");
            out.println("<DT><B>" + name + "</B> (" + email + ") says");
            out.println("<DD><PRE>" + comment + "</PRE>");
            out.println("</DL>");
            // Sleep for half a second to simulate a slow data source
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        }
    }
    private void printFooter(PrintWriter out) throws ServletException {
        out.println("</BODY>");
        out.println("</HTML>");
    }
    private void handleForm(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res) {
        GuestbookEntry entry = new GuestbookEntry();
        entry.name = req.getParameter("name");
        entry.email = req.getParameter("email");
        entry.comment = req.getParameter("comment");
        entries.addElement(entry);
        // Make note we have a new last modified time
        lastModified = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    public long getLastModified(HttpServletRequest req) {
        return lastModified;
    }
}
class GuestbookEntry {
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String comment;
}
```

And in the XML file i used

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>
GuestBook
</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
Guestbook
</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>
GuestBook
</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>
/hello.html
</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

everything i used are fine but tomcat still gives me a 404 error. although i tried by different methods but still it gives me an error.
if someone will provide a solution then it would be really appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try with complete classname i.e. with package name for `<servlet-class>` and try the wildcard _*_ for `<url-pattern>`

Comment: there are 4 ways for mapping and i tried all but still it gives an error.

Comment: Where are your class files located? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: yes i am using Eclipse for javaEE

Comment: have you tried giving absolute path in XML and client side?

Comment: yes i have tried 4 ways but it is giving an error :(

Comment: Please post your html file

Comment: you can see it in the code, it posts to itself.

Comment: What you have posted is the servlet file and XML file

Comment: @NaveedAli There should be a html or jsp file. It is by default `index.html` file. It generates the requests coming to the server. Your servlet has the code to generate response for such request. But initially there should be a way to send a request, which could be through a index.html file with a simple form or a button. If you imported this project, try to build it by creating a new project and creating files.

Comment: this servlet class by default creates a request and then generates a response. I copied this example from book and this example have an output in a book but when i run it on server, then it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

we would need to create a separate html page and will write the same content as "PrintForm" method in the code. if we do so then this servlet will work perfectly. Although this servlet used for server cache, i hope it will help you in future.

thank you